# Splitting string which includes( / and : ) into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, split

I have a string that includes date and time together. I need all of them seperated in some cases. 
My string is like this : 28/08/2015 11:37:47

There are some solutions in there but they do not fix my problem

```
var date = "12/15/2009";
var parts = date.split("/");
alert(parts[0]); // 12
alert(parts[1]); // 15
alert(parts[2]); // 2009
```

This is similar thing but as I said above, I need to split all of them.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have that datetime format I'd suggest a simple regex

```
"28/08/2015 11:37:47".split(/\/|\s|:/)
```

This splits it on a / a space and the colon

and will return

```
 ["28", "08", "2015", "11", "37", "47"]
```

**Edit as per question asked in comment**

```js
function parse() {
  /** INPUT FORMAT NEEDS TO BE DAY/MONTH/YEAR in numbers for this to work **/
  var datetime= document.getElementById("datetime").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output")
  var datetimearr = datetime.split(/\/|\s|:/);
  var timearr = time.split(/:/);
  var date = new Date(datetimearr[2],datetimearr[1]-1,datetimearr[0],datetimearr[3],datetimearr[4],datetimearr[5]);
  date.setHours(date.getHours()+(parseInt(timearr[0])));//parseInt needed otherwise it will default to string concatenation
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+(parseInt(timearr[1])));
  date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds()+(parseInt(timearr[2])));
  output.value = date.toString();
}
```

```html
Date time: <input type="text" value="28/08/2015 11:37:47" id="datetime"><BR/>
Time to add: <input type="text" value="11:37:47" id="time"><input type="button" value="calculate!" onclick="parse()"><BR/>
<textarea  id="output" placeholder="Output comes here" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution for me

Comment: The website blocks me to open a new title in 90 minutes. Do you know the solution of this problem -> 
Adding (hh:mm:ss) to (YYYY/mm/dd hh:mm:ss) in Javascript

Comment: sorry, you want to do what? in a date object or in a string object?

Comment: I added a snippet to my answer. take a look at it. I really need to know what you want to do... Do you wish to modify an array, create a string or create a date object?

Comment: I am gonna get this objects in html form, and read them in js with getElementById function. To imagine;
var datetime= document.getElementById("datetime1").value;
var time= document.getElementById("time1").value;
var sumofdatetime= datetime+time; 
I hope, i could clarify it. Namely as math example: 
Input1: 01/01/2015 12:00:00
Input2: 28:10:00
output: 02/01/2015 16:10:00

Comment: This is another problem of me. I asked in here, because the website does not allow me to open a new header in 90 minutes

Comment: Take a look at the new snippet, this does what you need. + you get a nice date object to fiddle with :-) Also, if this is the solution you need, please mark the check icon to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions.

```js
var str = '28/08/2015 11:37:47';

console.log(str.split(/[\/:\s]/));
```

Comment: Was just about to answer but you got there, so I won't bother. This is what I would use! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert the string to date by:

```
var datestr = "12/15/2009 11:33:44";
var date = new Date(datestr);
```

And now access the values by those functions:

```
date.getDate(); //  -> 15
date.getMonth(); //  -> 12
date.getFullYear(); //  -> 2009
date.getHours(); //  -> 11
date.getMinutes(); //  -> 33
date.getSeconds(); //  -> 44
```

[working js fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/0dke8974/)

EDIT: Had to fix example because `document.write` didn't work correctly on Fiddle.

Comment: That is not a standard date format so this is not guaranteed to work in all environments.